# rabbitmq client hangs while trying to declare queue

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I tried searching for solution of my problem but could not find it stack overflow.

**Issue**
When a user tries to declare a queue or exchange, in a corner case where RabbitMQ server is having some issue, the client keeps waiting without any timeout which causes the thread calling the rabbitmq to always remain in waiting state (wait which never ends).

Below is stacktrace

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:50)
    - locked <0x00000007bb0464c8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:89)
    - locked <0x00000007bb0464c8> (a com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:343)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:216)
    at 
(AMQChannel.java:118)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:833)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:917)
    - locked <0x00000007bb555300> (a java.lang.Object)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy293.queueDeclare(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueues(RabbitAdmin.java:575)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.access$200(RabbitAdmin.java:66)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$12.doInRabbit(RabbitAdmin.java:504)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.initialize(RabbitAdmin.java:500)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin$11.onCreate(RabbitAdmin.java:419)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CompositeConnectionListener.onCreate(CompositeConnectionListener.java:33)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:553)
    - locked <0x00000007bb057828> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1412)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1388)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.declareQueue(RabbitAdmin.java:207)
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Declaration of queues is currently in my postconstruct of beans calling our component handling messaging, thus not letting any new bean create.

**UPDATE**
The issue came again on our prod server. When trying to connect via amqp-client-3.4.2 directly it seems working. But from spring-rabbit-1.6.7.RELEASE, spring-amqp-1.6.7.RELEASE it is not working.

Via amqp-client-3.4.2

```
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("<<HOST NAME>>");
        factory.setUsername("<<USERNAME>>");
        factory.setPassword("<<PASSWORD>>");
        factory.setVirtualHost("<<VIRTUAL HOST>>");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, true, false, false, null);
```

[Code flow with rabbit-amqp client](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_16AqVu8zNGyOXQczU8VWMVDkns2uTco)

Spring way which is not working

```
        CachingConnectionFactory factory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("<<HOST NAME>>");
        factory.setUsername("<<USERNAME>>");
        factory.setPassword("<<PASSWORD>>");
        factory.setVirtualHost("<<VIRTUAL HOST>>");

        RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(factory);
        Queue queue = new Queue(QUEUE_NAME);
        admin.declareQueue(queue);
```

[Code flow with spring amqp](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lZ39UJXOHPERFKQ3apa0HsPZBlfRrD8H)

This issue occurs rarely and we are still trying to figure out the reason behind this behavior. We tried setting connection timeout but did not worked in our test program.

On debugging it further it looks like an exception is not letting notification sent back to our code. For client not found kind of issues, we are getting exception properly.

We are using RabbitMQ 3.6.10 and Erlang 19.3.4 on CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Answer (score 2):

> Declaration of queues is currently in my postconstruct of beans

I can't speak to the hang but you should NEVER interact with the broker from post construct, `afterPropertiesSet()` etc. It is too early in the application context lifecycle.

There are several work arounds - implement `SmartLifecycle`; return `true` from `isAutoStartup()` and put the bean in an early phase (see `Phased`). `start()` will be called after the application context is fully created.

However, it's generally better to just define the queues, bindings etc as beans and let the framework take care of doing all the declarations for you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. It is consumers of our messaging components who are calling it via Postconstruct. We are trying to rectify this as well. But currently we are also looking to fix this issue.

Comment: I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and/or look at a [network trace, for example with Wireshark](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-wireshark.html) to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I had something semi-similar happen, which I'll share in case it helps anyone.

It appears to me that a call to "rabbitAdmin.declareQueue" will wait for any ongoing publisher-confirm callbacks to complete. I couldn't find this documented anywhere but this was the behaviour I witnessed.

In my case, a separate thread (Thread #2) was processing a publisher-confirmation while Thread #1 was trying to declare a queue (and hanging). Thread #1 was waiting for Thread #2 to complete, but in my case I had a deadlock due to some funky database-locking I was doing which actually caused Thread #2 to also wait for Thread #1 to complete.

The solution was for me to stop doing significant processing in publisher-confirmation callbacks. In my callback, I actually just launch *yet another* thread to do the real processing. This allows my publisher-confirmation callback to return almost-immediately, releasing any potential deadlocks.